# NSOperation inside setCompletionBlock another block handling

Tags: ios, file-upload, block, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have little tricky question :

```
NSOperation *operation = [[NSOperation alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary * dictFileData  = [arrData objectAtIndex:operationCounter];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{

[self uploadFileOnAWSServer:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaFileData"] MediaType:[[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaType"]integerValue] MediaKeyName:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"uploadKeyName"] MediaContentType:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaContentType"]];

    }];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

and for method uploadfileONAWSserve....
I have another block and its separate completion block.

In this way I have to upload multiple files on AWS server and once all files completion done I have to call service on my server.
Now I need to handle this complete scenario with multiple post with Success and failure cases.

Can anybody explain how can I handle it proper way with all success and failure cases.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd add dependencies to your operations:

```
NSOperation *uploadOperationA = // upload operation
NSOperation *uploadOperationB = // upload operation

NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        // do stuff when other operations complete
    }];

[completionOperation addDependency:uploadOperationA];
[completionOperation addDependency:uploadOperationB];
```

However, you added the actual operation you want to perform in a completion block - and it is executed **after** the opearation's `finished` property is set to `YES` - and if an operation has dependencies, it is ready to execute when all the dependencies have `finished` set to `YES`. So in your case, the completion operation would execute before your uploads actually complete

Instead do:

```
NSOperation *uploadOperationA = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self uploadFileOnAWSServer:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaFileData"] MediaType:[[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaType"]integerValue] MediaKeyName:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"uploadKeyName"] MediaContentType:[dictFileData valueForKey:@"MediaContentType"]];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_release(sema);
    }];
}];
```

`dispatch_semaphore_t` is necessary because, I assume, `uploadFileOnAWSServer` is asynchronous, and therefore will return immediately, before completing actual upload. In that case, somewhere in `uploadFileOnAWSServer` (perhaps completion block?) you should put

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
```

If that function is not asynchronous, you can ditch the semaphore completely